# php file uploading permissions, which would be the best chmod?

Tags: php, file-permissions

I am creating a site that users can upload images to and I am not sure what the best permissions would be?  I was going to use 0777 but decided that was a very bad idea after reading some of the other questions on here.

What would be the best permission value to use to allow users to upload files without compromising security?

Also, is there a way of changing the permissions recursively so the subfolders are changed at the same time?  One of the user contributed notes on php.net suggests using chmod_R but it doesn't seem a value command?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions should be sufficient for the webserver to write to it.

So change the directory ownership to the webserver user and the possible permissions can be even `0700`

To change permissions recursively use

```
chmod -R ...
```

Comment: Don't forget that config files, if not outside public reach, could be read-only if the webserver is not going to modify them.

Comment: @Alfabravo: I was actually speaking about the upload directory permissions specifically.

Comment: for the uploaded files, `0600` is even better that `0700`, since there's no need to execute them, as they are supposed to be images

Comment: @tmuguet: for the files - yes, I've given an advice about permissions for the upload directory

Answer (score 0):

You may change the directories' permissions with

```
find /path/ -type d -exec chmod XYZ '{}' \;
```

and the files' permissions with

```
find /path/ -type f -exec chmod XYZ '{}' \;
```

I usually put the guid bit high with 2 so that the new directories preserve the group owner, and I put me as the owner and apache as the group owner.

This way if I ever need to create a file from the shell apache will be able to read them (sometime happens). Giving just the ownership to apache is also a good option.

So I'd say

```
 2750 to directories (with me owner and apache group)
```

and

```
 640 to files
```